# Apache files directive for single file

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, wordpress

I'm trying to restrict access to the `wp-login.php` file of a wordpress installation to a single IP address using the following .htaccess directive:

```
<Files wp-login.php>
    order deny,allow
    allow from y.y.y.y # Actual IP address replaced
    deny from all
</Files>
```

This works but it's also Denying access to wp-login.php files within the /public_html/subdomains directory. I've tried wrapping the Files directive inside a Directory directive like so:

```
   <Directory />
    Order allow,deny
    <Files wp-login.php>
       Order deny,allow
       allow from y.y.y.y
       deny from all
    </Files>
   </Directory>
```

But this just gives me a 500 Internal Server Error. I've also tried replacing the / in the Directory match with /public_html to no avail

Is there a way I can get the FilesMatch directive to only match the /public_html/wp-login.php file and not those inside the subdomains directory?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're encountering is cause by

> The directives given within this section will be applied to any object with a basename (last component of filename) matching the specified filename.

So your files directive will match anything ending in  wp-login.php.

The solution is to wrap it in a `<Directory>` block to limit it's scope

```
<Directory /path/to/wp-login>
    <Files wp-login.php>
        Order deny,allow
        allow from y.y.y.y
        deny from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

---

FWIW [duosecurity](https://www.duosecurity.com/) have an integration that adds two factor auth to WP logins. It works really well.

Comment: This won't work. The FilesMatch directive works in the same way as Files in that it only compares the basename of the file, not the directory

Comment: A Directory directive cannot be placed inside .htaccess files

Comment: @Andy: Why are you doing this in a .htaccess file then - use the main server config.

Comment: I don't have access to the server config, it's on a shared server. I did say I was using the .htaccess file in my question. I think my only option is to move the subdomains out of the public_html directory. Thanks anyway